# Redirect a user trying to download a .zip file to download.php?file=fileName in IIS

Tags: php, redirect, iis, web-config

I need to prevent people from downloading `.zip` files in my server unless they are logged in. For this purpose and since I'm also using MediaWiki and I would like to have to modify the least this as I'm not familiar with it I was thinking about doing the following:

When a user wants to download a `.zip` file, it will be redirected by the server (with a `web.config` rule) to something like `download.php?file=fileName` and inside the PHP, I can do my programming to see if he's logged in and then use readFile() to give him the file.

However I'm not familiar with IIS (not much more with Apache either) and I'm totally clueless as how to write this rule. Could someone please help me out on this?

I'm also open to other suggestions. Putting the upload folder in a place not accessible to the public (but to the server) may do the trick but images are also uploaded then and then they wouldn't download. I could, again modify the behavior of the upload system myself but as it's done by MediaWiki I would prefer not to.

I have found this code (by using a `.htaccess` to `web.config` online translator) but it's not working. Maybe it's easier for you to just fix this code:

http://pastebin.com/waMJnFyK

The uploads are in subdirectories within /images like for example /images/a/ae/file.zip and I would like that when you try to open that you get redirected to a php file where as a GET input I have the file location.

Comment: I would suggest making use of `URL Rewrite`. Such that a call to a `fileName.zip` url is then rewritten to `download.php?file=fileName` so that you can confirm the user is logged in. FYI you can import Rewrite cond and rules from .htaccess into IIS URL Rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I took: http://pastebin.com/7skGT9uN

It redirects everything that ends in .zip within /images to download.php?fileName=whatever where the /images part is not passed.